# Encoding problem with rails 3 application with post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, character-encoding, internationalization, http-post, symbols

How can it be that some members of the development team have no problem with sending Post request with Russian symbols from form, but other members - have? All members are using Ubuntu.

The error is: "There were problems with the following fields: Username should use only letters, numbers, spaces, and .-_@ please."

model:
validates_presence_of :username, :email
validates_uniqueness_of :username

view:
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    
      <%= f.label :username %>
      <%= f.text_field :username %>
    
    
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    
    
      <%= f.submit "Change" %>
    
<% end %>

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a validation error, but your validations don't seem to include it. Are you sure you're looking at the right model file?